# Unable to make a 'forem' in Rails due to JRuby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, forem

I have tried multiple times to fix this problem, but it keeps popping up. Whenever I run bundle install with my 'forem' in the Gemfile, it gives me this error:

```
Fetching git://github.com/radar/forem.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Installing rake (10.0.3)
Installing i18n (0.6.4)
Installing multi_json (1.7.0)
Installing activesupport (3.2.12)
Installing builder (3.0.4)
Installing activemodel (3.2.12)
Installing erubis (2.7.0)
Installing journey (1.0.4)
Installing rack (1.4.5)
Installing rack-cache (1.2)
Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
Installing hike (1.2.1)
Installing tilt (1.3.5)
Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
Installing actionpack (3.2.12)
Installing mime-types (1.21)
Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
Installing treetop (1.4.12)
Installing mail (2.4.4)
Installing actionmailer (3.2.12)
Installing arel (3.0.2)
Installing tzinfo (0.3.37)
Installing activerecord (3.2.12)
Installing activerecord-jdbc-adapter (1.2.8)
Installing jdbc-sqlite3 (3.7.2.1)
Installing activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter (1.2.7)
Installing activeresource (3.2.12)
Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
Installing blankslate (3.1.2)
Installing bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0147)
Using bundler (1.3.4)
Installing cancan (1.6.8)
Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.1)
Installing execjs (1.4.0)
Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
Installing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
Installing json (1.7.7)
Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
Installing thor (0.17.0)
Installing railties (3.2.12)
Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Installing decorators (1.0.3)
Installing orm_adapter (0.4.0)
Installing warden (1.2.1)
Installing devise (2.2.3)
Installing ffi (1.0.11)
Installing rubypython (0.5.3)
Installing pygments.rb (0.2.4)
Installing redcarpet (2.0.1)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.2/bin/jruby extconf.rb
NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS or modify .jrubyrc to enable.

(root) at /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:8
require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027
(root) at /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
(root) at extconf.rb:1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/username/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/redcarpet-2.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/username/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.2/gems/redcarpet-2.0.1/ext/redcarpet/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing redcarpet (2.0.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install redcarpet -v '2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have tried to pass "-Xcext.enabled=true" to JRuby, but it still gives me this error. Please help!

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try kramdown instead of redcarpet. http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/